# White board for multi channel using node js

Tags: javascript, html, sockets

Hi All Node JS expert:

I have build a white board suing node js with socket.io as below:

server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(6060);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('mydraw', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.emit('mydraw', data);
  });
```

client calling conencting http://www.mysrver.com:6060  using html5 with a canvas. Now the issue is whoever connecting on the clinet html on port 6060 like  http://www.mysrver.com:6060/index.html 
Can capable to draw line in the canvas.

I want to make it channel based ... mean on same port 6060. user can join many channel to make the drawing private. Exmaple:

user a
user b

can join and draw to `http://www.mysrver.com:6060/1234`

here channel name = 1234

user c
user d

can join and draw to  `http://www.mysrver.com:6060/5678`

here channel name = 5678

what change i need to do in the server.js?

Answer (score 0):

You should [utilize the 'rooms' functionality](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('mydraw', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.to('roomName').emit('mydraw', data);
  });

  socket.join('roomName');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! for the reply. In the client html5 i am connection to the socket using 'var socket = io.connect('http://www.myserver.com:6060'); can you show hot to define the room name and connect from html clinet ?